# Fedex Rest Create Shipment API Invalid field value in the input error coming

Tags: laravel, rest, guzzle, fedex

I am trying to integrate FedEx Create Shipment API in my E-Commerce Project. I am using laravel as the backend framework. Below is my code:-

```
$product = Product::find($orderDetail->product_id);
        if ($product->type == 'digital') return;

        $fedexRestApiCredentials = FedExRestApi::whereSellerId(auth()->id())->latest()->first();
        $fedexRestApiCredentials->fedex_client_id = decrypt($fedexRestApiCredentials->fedex_client_id);
        $fedexRestApiCredentials->fedex_client_secret = decrypt($fedexRestApiCredentials->fedex_client_secret);
        $fedexRestApiCredentials->fedex_account_number = decrypt($fedexRestApiCredentials->fedex_account_number);

        $sellerId = $orderDetail->seller_id;
        $seller = User::find($sellerId);
        $sellerProfile = SellerProfile::whereUserId($sellerId)->first();

        $seller->phone = str_replace(' ', '', $seller->phone);
        $seller->phone = str_replace('(', '', $seller->phone);
        $seller->phone = str_replace(')', '', $seller->phone);
        $seller->phone = str_replace('-', '', $seller->phone);
        $seller->phone = '1' . $seller->phone;

        $sellerAddress = SellerAddress::whereSellerId($sellerId)->first();
        $streetLines[] = $sellerAddress->line1;
        $streetLines[] = $sellerAddress->line2;
        $streetLines = array_filter($streetLines);

        $buyerAddress = BuyerAddress::whereBuyerId($orderDetail->order->buyer_id)->whereIsDefault('1')->first();
        $streetLinesBuyer = [];
        $streetLinesBuyer[] = $buyerAddress->street_address;
        $streetLinesBuyer[] = $buyerAddress->others;
        $streetLinesBuyer = array_filter($streetLinesBuyer);

        $userId = auth()->id();
        $buyer = User::find($userId);

        $buyer->phone = str_replace(' ', '', $buyer->phone);
        $buyer->phone = str_replace('(', '', $buyer->phone);
        $buyer->phone = str_replace(')', '', $buyer->phone);
        $buyer->phone = str_replace('-', '', $buyer->phone);
        $buyer->phone = '1' . $buyer->phone;

        $fedexStateToken = FedexStateToken::notExpired()->whereCreatedBy($sellerId)->latest()->value('token');
        if (is_null($fedexStateToken)) {
            $auth = (new \FedexRest\Authorization\Authorize())
                ->setClientId($fedexRestApiCredentials->fedex_client_id)
                ->setClientSecret($fedexRestApiCredentials->fedex_client_secret)
                ->authorize();
            FedexStateToken::create([
                'token' => $auth->access_token,
                'expiry_date' => now()->addHour(),
                'token_type' => $auth->token_type,
                'scope' => $auth->scope,
                'created_by' => $sellerId
            ]);
            $fedexStateToken = $auth->access_token;
        }

        $headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $fedexStateToken,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ];

        $requestedPackageLineItems[] = (object) [
            'sequenceNumber' => $product->id,
            'groupPackageCount' => 1,
            'weight' => (object) [
                'units' => $product->weight_unit,
                'value' => (float) $product->weight_value
            ],
            'dimensions' => (object) [
                'length' => $product->length,
                'width' => $product->width,
                'height' => $product->height,
                'units' => $product->dimension_unit
            ],
            'itemDescription' => $product->description
        ];

        $input = new \stdClass();

        $input = (object) [
            'mergeLabelDocOption' => "LABELS_AND_DOCS",
            'requestedShipment' => (object) [
                'shipDatestamp' => now()->format('Y-m-d'),
                'shipper' => (object) [
                    'address' => (object) [
                        'streetLines' => $streetLines,
                        'city' => $sellerAddress->city,
                        'stateOrProvinceCode' => $sellerAddress->state,
                        'postalCode' => $sellerAddress->postcode,
                        'countryCode' => $sellerAddress->country_code
                    ],
                    'contact' => (object) [
                        'personName' => $seller->full_name,
                        'emailAddress' => $seller->email,
                        'phoneNumber' => $seller->phone,
                        'companyName' => $sellerProfile->business_name
                    ]
                ],
                'soldTo' => (object) [
                    'address' => (object) [
                        'streetLines' => $streetLines,
                        'city' => $sellerAddress->city,
                        'stateOrProvinceCode' => $sellerAddress->state,
                        'postalCode' => $sellerAddress->postcode,
                        'countryCode' => $sellerAddress->country_code
                    ],
                    'contact' => (object) [
                        'personName' => $seller->full_name,
                        'emailAddress' => $seller->email,
                        'phoneNumber' => $seller->phone,
                        'companyName' => $sellerProfile->business_name
                    ],
                    'accountNumber' => (object) [
                        'value' => $fedexRestApiCredentials->fedex_account_number
                    ]
                ],
                'recipients' => (object) [
                    'address' => (object) [
                        'streetLines' => $streetLinesBuyer,
                        'city' => $buyerAddress->city,
                        'stateOrProvinceCode' => $buyerAddress->state,
                        'postalCode' => $buyerAddress->zip,
                        'countryCode' => $buyerAddress->country_code
                    ],
                    'contact' => (object) [
                        'personName' => $buyer->full_name,
                        'emailAddress' => $buyer->email,
                        'phoneNumber' => $buyer->phone
                    ]
                ],
                'pickupType' => "USE_SCHEDULED_PICKUP",
                "serviceType" => $orderDetail->service_type,
                "packagingType" => "YOUR_PACKAGING",
                'totalWeight' => (float) $product->weight_value,
                'origin' => (object) [
                    'address' => (object) [
                        'streetLines' => $streetLines,
                        'city' => $sellerAddress->city,
                        'stateOrProvinceCode' => $sellerAddress->state,
                        'postalCode' => $sellerAddress->postcode,
                        'countryCode' => $sellerAddress->country_code
                    ],
                    'contact' => (object) [
                        'personName' => $seller->full_name,
                        'emailAddress' => $seller->email,
                        'phoneNumber' => $seller->phone,
                        'companyName' => $sellerProfile->business_name
                    ]
                ],
                'shippingChargesPayment' => (object) [
                    'paymentType' => "SENDER",
                    'payor' => (object) [
                        'responsibleParty' => (object) [
                            'address' => (object) [
                                'streetLines' => $streetLines,
                                'city' => $sellerAddress->city,
                                'stateOrProvinceCode' => $sellerAddress->state,
                                'postalCode' => $sellerAddress->postcode,
                                'countryCode' => $sellerAddress->country_code
                            ],
                            'contact' => (object) [
                                'personName' => $seller->full_name,
                                'emailAddress' => $seller->email,
                                'phoneNumber' => $seller->phone,
                                'companyName' => $sellerProfile->business_name
                            ],
                            'accountNumber' => (object) [
                                'value' => $fedexRestApiCredentials->fedex_account_number
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'emailNotificationDetail' => (object) [
                    'aggregationType' => "PER_PACKAGE",
                    'emailNotificationRecipients' => [
                        (object)[
                            'name' => $buyer->full_name,
                            'emailNotificationRecipientType' => "RECIPIENT",
                            'emailAddress' => $buyer->email,
                            "notificationFormatType" => "HTML",
                            "notificationType" => "EMAIL",
                            "notificationEventType" => [
                                "ON_DELIVERY",
                                "ON_EXCEPTION",
                                "ON_SHIPMENT",
                                "ON_TENDER",
                                "ON_PICKUP",
                                "ON_ESTIMATED_DELIVERY",
                                "ON_LABEL",
                                "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_ARRIVED",
                                "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_ASSIGNED",
                                "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_DEPARTED",
                                "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_EN_ROUTE"
                            ]
                        ],
                        (object)[
                            'name' => $seller->full_name,
                            'emailNotificationRecipientType' => "SHIPPER",
                            'emailAddress' => $seller->email,
                            "notificationFormatType" => "HTML",
                            "notificationType" => "EMAIL",
                            "notificationEventType" => [
                                "ON_DELIVERY",
                                "ON_EXCEPTION",
                                "ON_SHIPMENT",
                                "ON_TENDER",
                                "ON_PICKUP",
                                "ON_ESTIMATED_DELIVERY",
                                "ON_LABEL",
                                "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_ARRIVED",
                                "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_ASSIGNED",
                                "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_DEPARTED",
                                "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_EN_ROUTE"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'blockInsightVisibility' => FALSE,
                'labelSpecification' => (object) [
                    'labelFormatType' => "COMMON2D",
                    'labelStockType' => "PAPER_7X475",
                    'labelRotation' => "LEFT",
                    'imageType' => "PDF"
                ],
                'rateRequestType' => ["PREFERRED"],
                'preferredCurrency' => 'USD',
                'totalPackageCount' => 1,
                'requestedPackageLineItems' => $requestedPackageLineItems,
            ],
            'labelResponseOptions' => "URL_ONLY",
            'accountNumber' => (object) [
                'value' => $fedexRestApiCredentials->fedex_account_number
            ],
            'shipAction' => "CONFIRM",
            'processingOptionType' => 'SYNCHRONOUS_ONLY',
            'oneLabelAtATime' => FALSE
        ];

        $client = new Client();
        $request = $client->request('POST', env('FEDEX_REST_API_URL') . '/ship/v1/shipments', [
            'headers' => $headers,
            'json' => $input,
        ]);
        $response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
        $response = json_decode($response);
```

Following is the Payload object that is being generated:-

```
{
    "mergeLabelDocOption": "LABELS_AND_DOCS",
    "requestedShipment": {
        "shipDatestamp": "2023-05-17",
        "shipper": {
            "address": {
                "streetLines": [
                    "1309 S Agnew Avenue",
                    "Apt 303"
                ],
                "city": "Oklahoma City",
                "stateOrProvinceCode": "OK",
                "postalCode": "73108",
                "countryCode": "US"
            },
            "contact": {
                "personName": "Kattie Ortiz",
                "emailAddress": "dorthy.glover@gmail.com",
                "phoneNumber": "17182934300",
                "companyName": "Kyle Wilderman LLC"
            }
        },
        "soldTo": {
            "address": {
                "streetLines": [
                    "1309 S Agnew Avenue",
                    "Apt 303"
                ],
                "city": "Oklahoma City",
                "stateOrProvinceCode": "OK",
                "postalCode": "73108",
                "countryCode": "US"
            },
            "contact": {
                "personName": "Kattie Ortiz",
                "emailAddress": "dorthy.glover@gmail.com",
                "phoneNumber": "17182934300",
                "companyName": "Kyle Wilderman LLC"
            },
            "accountNumber": {
                "value": "XXXXXXXXX"
            }
        },
        "recipients": {
            "address": {
                "streetLines": [
                    "13450 Farmcrest Ct"
                ],
                "city": "Herndon",
                "stateOrProvinceCode": "VA",
                "postalCode": "20171",
                "countryCode": "US"
            },
            "contact": {
                "personName": "Kattie Ortiz",
                "emailAddress": "dorthy.glover@gmail.com",
                "phoneNumber": "17182934300"
            }
        },
        "pickupType": "USE_SCHEDULED_PICKUP",
        "serviceType": "FEDEX_GROUND",
        "packagingType": "YOUR_PACKAGING",
        "totalWeight": 50,
        "origin": {
            "address": {
                "streetLines": [
                    "1309 S Agnew Avenue",
                    "Apt 303"
                ],
                "city": "Oklahoma City",
                "stateOrProvinceCode": "OK",
                "postalCode": "73108",
                "countryCode": "US"
            },
            "contact": {
                "personName": "Kattie Ortiz",
                "emailAddress": "dorthy.glover@gmail.com",
                "phoneNumber": "17182934300",
                "companyName": "Kyle Wilderman LLC"
            }
        },
        "shippingChargesPayment": {
            "paymentType": "SENDER",
            "payor": {
                "responsibleParty": {
                    "address": {
                        "streetLines": [
                            "1309 S Agnew Avenue",
                            "Apt 303"
                        ],
                        "city": "Oklahoma City",
                        "stateOrProvinceCode": "OK",
                        "postalCode": "73108",
                        "countryCode": "US"
                    },
                    "contact": {
                        "personName": "Kattie Ortiz",
                        "emailAddress": "dorthy.glover@gmail.com",
                        "phoneNumber": "17182934300",
                        "companyName": "Kyle Wilderman LLC"
                    },
                    "accountNumber": {
                        "value": "XXXXXXXXX"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "emailNotificationDetail": {
            "aggregationType": "PER_PACKAGE",
            "emailNotificationRecipients": [
                {
                    "name": "Kattie Ortiz",
                    "emailNotificationRecipientType": "RECIPIENT",
                    "emailAddress": "dorthy.glover@gmail.com",
                    "notificationFormatType": "HTML",
                    "notificationType": "EMAIL",
                    "notificationEventType": [
                        "ON_DELIVERY",
                        "ON_EXCEPTION",
                        "ON_SHIPMENT",
                        "ON_TENDER",
                        "ON_PICKUP",
                        "ON_ESTIMATED_DELIVERY",
                        "ON_LABEL",
                        "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_ARRIVED",
                        "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_ASSIGNED",
                        "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_DEPARTED",
                        "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_EN_ROUTE"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Kattie Ortiz",
                    "emailNotificationRecipientType": "SHIPPER",
                    "emailAddress": "dorthy.glover@gmail.com",
                    "notificationFormatType": "HTML",
                    "notificationType": "EMAIL",
                    "notificationEventType": [
                        "ON_DELIVERY",
                        "ON_EXCEPTION",
                        "ON_SHIPMENT",
                        "ON_TENDER",
                        "ON_PICKUP",
                        "ON_ESTIMATED_DELIVERY",
                        "ON_LABEL",
                        "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_ARRIVED",
                        "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_ASSIGNED",
                        "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_DEPARTED",
                        "ON_PICKUP_DRIVER_EN_ROUTE"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "blockInsightVisibility": false,
        "labelSpecification": {
            "labelFormatType": "COMMON2D",
            "labelStockType": "PAPER_7X475",
            "labelRotation": "LEFT",
            "imageType": "PDF"
        },
        "rateRequestType": [
            "PREFERRED"
        ],
        "preferredCurrency": "USD",
        "totalPackageCount": 1,
        "requestedPackageLineItems": [
            {
                "sequenceNumber": 7,
                "groupPackageCount": 1,
                "weight": {
                    "units": "LB",
                    "value": 50
                },
                "dimensions": {
                    "length": 20,
                    "width": 20,
                    "height": 10,
                    "units": "IN"
                },
                "itemDescription": "Ea exercitation impe"
            }
        ]
    },
    "labelResponseOptions": "URL_ONLY",
    "accountNumber": {
        "value": "XXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "shipAction": "CONFIRM",
    "processingOptionType": "SYNCHRONOUS_ONLY",
    "oneLabelAtATime": false
}
```

I am using the Sandbox API ('https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com') & I'm getting this error:-

```
code: "INVALID.INPUT.EXCEPTION"
message: "Invalid field value in the input"
transactionId: "18f933ca-a570-4907-9102-ab9dcd561165"
```

can anyone please tell me what mistake I'm making that will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

**Note: All the data are from the test environment(means fake), hence I did not remove them**

Comment: The `Invalid field value` could mean lots of things, and unfortunately the error message is not very helpful. (is there more to the error message?) ... anyway, one thing I _do_ know is that the `line2` address should not be included in the request at all if there's no data. Not sure if that will solve the complaint, but is at least one place to check/try. Other than that, you'll have to double-check the other values to see what might be the issue. (or call FedEx's tech support, if necessary -- they've been helpful for me, when needed)

Comment: The only errors you get are like this. It returns nothing useful at all. Even their own supplied example generates a 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

I love how they're retiring the SOAP API but it's all the same garbage underneath, and a Fortune 500 company can't tell you which field in a 500-line JSON input file it didn't like.

So you just have to go over it with a fine-tooth comb in Postman / Fiddler looking for the mistake.

In my case, I had `"rateRequestType": "PREFERRED"` instead of `"rateRequestType": ["PREFERRED"]`.

In your case, it looks like `recipients` should be an array of objects, not an object. Why, you ask, since no FedEx service actually supports multiple recipients? Beats me, but I bet that's your problem.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely my problem. I fixed it a long time ago but it was a pain in the ass to find this issue.

Comment: "Postman / Fiddler" - How do you do that with the FedEx API?  I have exactly this problem except with the THIRD_PARTY payer section of the Ship API.